# help with causal tree diagrams

Tags: diagrams, code, trees

Can you please help me finding a code to write down a tree diagrams for causal inference?
I need to find something exactly like these two:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! IMHO these are not trees. You can use `tikz` or `tikz-cd` to draw such diagrams. This answer defines a style targeted at the construction of such schemes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcounter{mylabels}
\tikzset{label label/.code={\stepcounter{mylabels}},
label labels/.style={every label/.append style={label label,
    alias=mylabel-\number\value{mylabels}}},
fit in labels/.style={label labels,
execute at begin picture={\edef\myfirstlabel{\the\numexpr\value{mylabels}+1}},
execute at end picture={\edef\mylastlabel{\the\numexpr\value{mylabels}}
\path foreach \X in {\myfirstlabel,\the\numexpr\myfirstlabel+1,...,\mylastlabel}
{foreach \Anchor in {north,south,west,east} 
 {(mylabel-\X.\Anchor)}};}}}
\tikzcdset{mdiagram/.style={every arrow/.append style={-latex,semithick},
    /tikz/column sep=2em,/tikz/row sep=2em,
    /tikz/.cd,dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt},
    every label/.append style={overlay},fit in labels},
    }
\begin{document}
Some text.
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[mdiagram]
 & |[dot,label=above:\textsf{Court order (CO)}]| \arrow[d]& \\
 & |[dot,label=right:\textsf{Captain (C)}]| \arrow[dl] \arrow[dr]& \\
 |[dot,label=left:\textsf{A}]| \arrow[dr] & & 
    |[dot,label=right:\textsf{B}]| \arrow[dl]\\
 & |[dot,label=below:\textsf{Death (D)}]| & \\
\end{tikzcd}\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[mdiagram]
 & |[dot,label=above:\textsf{Court order (CO)}]| \arrow[d]& \\
 & |[dot,label=right:\textsf{Captain (C)}]| \arrow[dr]& \\
 |[dot,label=left:\textsf{A}=\textsf{type}]| \arrow[dr] & & 
    |[dot,label=right:\textsf{B}]| \arrow[dl]\\
 & |[dot,label=below:\textsf{Death (D)}]| & \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
More text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you help me finding a sort of guide on how to use tikz? i am a beginner and don't even know what tikz is. How can i create diagrams? thanks in advance

Comment: @halfaxa The pgfmanual is well written. You should get it with `texdoc tikz`.

Answer (score 1):

You also can do that with `pstricks`, namely the `psmatrix` environment, defined in `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{dotsize=4pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.1, linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=0pt, labelsep=3pt}
 \everypsbox{\scriptsize\sffamily}
 \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.6cm, colsep = 1cm]
%%%nodes
  & \dotnode{CO} \\%
  & \dotnode{C} \\%
  \dotnode{A}& & \dotnode{B} \\%
  & \dotnode{D}%
%%% labels
\uput[u](CO){Court Order (CO)}
\uput[r](C){ Captain (C)}
\uput[l](A){A}\uput[r](B){B}
\uput[d](D){Death (D)}
     %%% arrows
 \ncline{CO}{C}
 \ncline{C}{A} \ncline{C}{B}
 \ncline{A}{D} \ncline{B}{D}
 \end{psmatrix}
\hskip 6em
 \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.6cm, colsep = 1cm]
%%%nodes
  & \dotnode{CO} \\%
  & \dotnode{C} \\%
  \dotnode{A}& & \dotnode{B} \\%
  & \dotnode{D}%
    %%% labels
    \uput[u](CO){Court Order (CO)}
    \uput[r](C){ Captain (C)}
    \uput[l](A){A\,=\,True}\uput[r](B){B}
    \uput[d](D){Death (D)}
     %%% arrows
     \ncline{CO}{C}
     \ncline{C}{B}
     \ncline{A}{D} \ncline{B}{D}
     \end{psmatrix}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help....however i don't know anything about what you are talking about can you please help me? What is pstricks?

Comment: Pstricks is a  graphic package (and a family of specialised packages) which is an interface between latex and the powerful Adobe's `postscript` language (a page description language, which has become a standard in professional typesetting). `Pdf` is based on a subset of postscript, without its computing capabilities (that's why `pslatex` alone cannot compile pstricks code). To compile  a pstricks code, you have either use the `latex ->dvips -> pstopdf` way` or compile with`xelatex`.